# How to draw vertical average lines for overlapping histograms in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to draw with matplotlib two average vertical line for every overlapping histograms using a loop. I have managed to draw the first one, but I don't know how to draw the second one. I'm using two variables from a dataset to draw the histograms. One variable (feat) is categorical (0 - 1), and the other one (objective) is numerical. The code is the following:

```
for chas in df[feat].unique():
   plt.hist(df.loc[df[feat] == chas, objective], bins = 15, alpha = 0.5, density = True, label = chas)
   plt.axvline(df[objective].mean(), linestyle = 'dashed', linewidth = 2)
   plt.title(objective)
   plt.legend(loc = 'upper right')
```

I also have to add to the legend the mean and standard deviation values for each histogram.

How can I do it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you using `axes` to plot your figure. Pls see code below and the artist tutorial [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

mu1, sigma1 = 100, 8
mu2, sigma2 = 150, 15

x1 = mu1 + sigma1 * np.random.randn(10000)
x2 = mu2 + sigma2 * np.random.randn(10000)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
# the histogram of the data
lbs = ['a', 'b']
colors = ['r', 'g']
for i, x in enumerate([x1, x2]):
    n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x, 50, density=True, facecolor=colors[i], alpha=0.75, label=lbs[i])
    ax.axvline(bins.mean())
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ted930511 for your response. But how can I do it from inside the loop? And add to the legend the mean and standard deviation values for each histogram?

Comment: You can use `label` within `hist`, if it solve your issue pls accept it. see updated code